# Hazelcast ItemListener stops fetching items

Tags: java, multithreading, message-queue, hazelcast

I have used hazelcast cache for distributed queueing and ItemListener for fetching the events from the queue. But printing this message quite a few times, the fetch from queue stops.

> 2018-06-11 01:26:26,231 INFO  [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.HealthMonitor] HealthMonitor: [xx.xx.xx.xx]:6701 [dev] [3.7.2] processors=4, physical.memory.total=7.7G, physical.memory.free=643.4M, swap.space.total=2.0G, swap.space.free=1.2G, heap.memory.used=2.1G, heap.memory.free=673.2M, heap.memory.total=2.7G, heap.memory.max=2.7G, heap.memory.used/total=75.82%, heap.memory.used/max=75.82%, minor.gc.count=8020, minor.gc.time=143849ms, major.gc.count=11, major.gc.time=6901ms, load.process=0.00%, load.system=0.00%, load.systemAverage=0.00%, thread.count=275, thread.peakCount=281, cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=8002555, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, operations.pending.invocations.count=1, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=1, connection.active.count=2, client.connection.count=1, connection.count=1

The listener stops fetching events from the queue while adding the events is still happening. How can I figure out why this is happening and why fetch from the queue is not working?

Comment: Your remaining heap size looks decreasing, which can lead some issues such as OOME. Can you please add more lines of logs and your implementation of both add and listen for items?

Comment: Are those Listener and publishers instance of Hazelcast Clients? There was improvements around them in recent versions so I'd try upgrading if possible